# LIKE operator in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In my SQL Server 2008 this simple statement doesn't work, I am really confused, please help me

```
Select * 
From Customer
where City like '%n';
```

And I am sure that I have lots of `City` ending with the letter `n`,

After executing it just shows my field's name.

Comment: What **datatype** is your `City` column in the datatase table??

Answer (score 0):

Your query will search for all cities ending with N and it ignores preceding characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values in the database are not getting padded with spaces or some other control character at the end.